# How to show that if K contains a complex root of unity, then every nonzero element of K has positive norm?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

I am trying to prove the following assertion:

If an algebraic number field $K$ contains a complex root of unity, then the norm of every nonzero element of $K$ is positive.

I think this is supposed to be a simple application of the theory of geometry of numbers, but I can't see how to prove it.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: Hint: the given hypotheses imply that $K$ has no real places, and hence the embeddings into $\mathbb{C}$ come in complex-conjugate pairs.

Comment: Thanks.  I see it now.  If K had a real embedding $\sigma$, then the group $W$ of roots of unity in K is isomorphic to the group $\sigma(W)$ of roots of unity in $\sigma(K)$.  But the hypotheses imply $|W| > 2$, while $|\sigma(W)| = 2$ because $\sigma(W)$ is real.